# Convergence, absolute convergence, divergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, absolute-convergence

Let the series
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{a_n}{3^n}}$ be convergent, but the series
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{{(-1)^n}{a_n}}{3^n}} $ be divergent.
Show whether:

a)$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{a_n}{3^n}}$ is absolutely convergent or conditionally convergent

b)$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{a_n}{2^n}}$ is absolutely/conditionally convergent or divergent

c)$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{a_n}{4^n}}$ is absolutely/conditionally convergent or divergent

d)Find the convergence radius of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{n+2}{n+3}a_nx^n}$

Okay, so far I have solved a), which I found quite easy to do, but I seem to get something wrong at b/c/d could someone please explain how they should be solved as it seems I have blocked completely...

Comment: well I tried the root test, but $ a_n $ confuses me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

We have

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{a_n}{3^n}\right|}=1$$

Hence, we must have

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|a_n\right|}=3$$

Comment: so $|a_n|<3^n$ ?

Comment: Actually, $|a_n|\le 3^n$.  Now, can you use this alone to ascertain all of the answers?  Not quite.  But you can use $\limsup_n \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=3$ to do so.

Comment: so $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{|a_n|}{3^n}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}{3}}=\frac{sth}{3}$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $sth$?

Comment: $sth=\lim sup_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$ i think?

Comment: Then, yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ahaaaaaaa, I get it now! Thank you very much!

Comment: Pleased to hear!  And you're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The series $\sum \frac {a_n}{3^n}$ must cause the ratio/root test to fail.  Otherwise, we couldn't have the conditional convergence as in a).

Comment: So what should be my next step?

Comment: Your next step should be to think for a little longer.  The ratio test fails only in a very specific case.  What does this information tell you about $a_n$?  Use this information to apply the ratio test to the other series.